# How to reduce tooltip appearance delay in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, preferences, ui, macos

When I hover some icon in Xcode I have to wait quite long for tooltip. How to reduce delay?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Tooltip delays can be adjusted globally from the command line. To reduce it to one millisecond (1/1000 second), fire up Terminal and enter:

```
defaults write -g NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 1
```

To only affect Xcode, tell the `defaults` command to only alter that value in the Xcode preferences domain, rather than setting it globally:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 1
```

I believe if you're running version 5 (?) or earlier of Xcode, the domain used to just be `com.apple.Xcode` , so:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 1
```

If I am missing some other prefs domain they've used, this command will show the top contenders:

```
defaults domains | tr -s ', ' '\n' | grep -i 'xcode'
```

To reset anything you've changed, just run the same command above you used to shorten it, but change the `1` on the end to the "factory default" setting of `1000` (1000 milliseconds = 1 second), e.g.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 1000
```